# What should I call an "injective" algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, definition

Given rings $A,B$, we say that $B$ is an $A$-algebra if there is a ring homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$. This homomorphism give the structure of the algebra. Various properties of algebras can either be said of $B$ or of $f$ (such as being flat, finite, finite type, integral, etc). **Is there a standard term to describe $B$ when $f$ is injective?** For example, "$B$ is a(n) [adjective] $A$-algebra".

Comment: Sometimes it is more conceptually or linguistically convenient to be specifically working in the category of $A$-algebras rather than just rings. Additionally, since algebras are often not injective, they tend to not be subrings. It would be awkward to keep flipping between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this called a *faithful* $A$-algebra, though I am not sure how universal this terminology is.  This comes from the much more common term "faithful $A$-module", which is an $A$-module $M$ such that for each nonzero $a\in A$ there exists $m\in M$ such that $am\neq 0$.  If $B$ is an $A$-algebra, then it is easy to see that it is faithful as an $A$-module iff the homomorphism $f:A\to B$ is injective.

Comment: Never seen it. Maybe they meant ‘faithful as $A$-module’, which indeed is a consequence of $f$ being injective.

Comment: Yes, that is where the term comes from.  I have added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.